# Множество категорий новостей

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Есть проблема с добавлением к новостям нескольких категорий. Объясню на примере киносайта - у одного фильма может быть несколько жанров. Какой при этом должна быть структура БД? И как примерно будет выглядеть код страницы с добавлением?

Answer (score 1):

Если используете MySQL, то связи там - весьма абстрактное понятие.

Вариантов два:

1. Использовать таблицу из примера [@Barton](/users/1971/barton)'а - удобно для случая, когда много записей в обеих таблицах.
2. Использовать поле типа `SET`. По скольку список жанров меняется редко, и их количество обычно не слишком велико, такое решение - в самый раз. Вы просто храните в этом поле `id` из таблицы жанров.

Единственный недостаток второго подхода - нужно каждый раз при изменении списка жанров (добавление или удаление) делать `ALTER` столбцу, что при **очень** большом кол-ве записей фильмов может занять определенное время.

Зато у него есть преимущество: поиск и выборка значений по этому полю с использованием `FIND_IN_SET()` будет происходить в бинарном режиме, что даст существенный прирост производительности!

Comment: На каком-то форуме читала, что используя SET? выборка производится медленнее, чуть позже попробую потестить :) По мне так второй способ более удобен, но с ним мне придется больше разбираться. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ага, я тоже "на каком-то форуме читал", что запросы с `LIMIT 40523,4` будет выполнять медленнее и с бОльшим потреблением памяти, чем если засунуть какое-то условие в `WHERE`, например, так

    WHERE id >= 40523 ADN id < 40527

Извращался, перестраивал запросы так и эдак, чтобы использовать такую конструкцию. А недавно убедился на примере таблицы с over 600 000 записей, что прироста - ноль!

Поэтому не верьте никому! Даже мне! Проверяйте сами, каждый проект уникален, и у вас все может быть по другому ))

З.Ы. Приятно видеть девушку в наших рядах ;-)

Comment: Ну чтож, теперь точно буду тестить set. :) Не смогу я смириться с тем, что бд пополнится еще одной огромной таблицей.

Comment: то что будет еще одна промежуточная таблица в которо1 будут всего 2 поля - ИД новостей и ИД категорий - это нормально, это называется 3 Нормальная Форма в БД

Answer (score 0):

Структура - многие ко многим. т.е. есть таблица новостей, есть таблица категрий и есть таблица которая хранит связь новости и категории. По поводу примера - слишком много писать :). Погуглите на счет примеров связи многие ко многим

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это будет самым простым и эффективным способом, правда не радует, что это увеличит количество записей в бд, хотя я не знаю, скажется ли это на производительности х)

Comment: ну поиск записей в таком случае будет быстрее и проще чем из п.2 @Johny. Хотя его вариант тоже годится, но могут быть проблемы с фильтрацией